# How do I make the bottom paragraph come underneath the header in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Complete newb here. Third question here.
How do I make the text "A Web Developer"
Come under "Hey I'm Hyde"
and how do I control the space between "A Web Developer" and "Hey I'm Hyde"?

I tried to use a line break but there has to be a better way. Line breaks did not work well.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 30px;
}

#links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

#links li:hover {
  background: blue;
}

#links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.45px;
}

#links {
  margin-right: 52px;
}

#welcome-section {
  padding-top: 60px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#big {
  font-size: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: gainsboro;
}

#projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45px 45px 45px;
  grid-template-rows: 45px 45px 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="flag.JPG" alt="logo" height="60px" />
    </div>
    <div id="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <p>
      <h1 id="big">
        Hey I'm Hyde
      </h1><br><br><br>

      <br>A Web Developer</p>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">Projects here</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Link to Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/so2w7rkp/

I wish to gain the ability to put the text "A web developer" underneath "Hey I'm hyde" for future flexbox projects.

Comment: please check i posted with small changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex-direction: column;

```
<section id="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="big">
        Hey I'm Hyde
    </h1>
    <small>A Web Developer</small>
</section>

#welcome-section {
   padding-top: 60px;
   height: calc(100vh - 60px);
   background-color: blue;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
```

}

[image]

Comment: How do I change the space between "Hey I'm Hyde" and "A Web Developer"? Also is there a way to control the space between "Hey I'm Hide" and the top navbar?

Comment: use  =》  justify-content: center;   justify-content: space-between;    justify-content: space-around;     or =>    padding

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 30px;
}

#links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

#links li:hover {
  background: blue;
}

#links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.45px;
}

#links {
  margin-right: 52px;
}

#welcome-section {
  padding-top: 60px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#welcome-section p:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 30px;
} 

#projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45px 45px 45px;
  grid-template-rows: 45px 45px 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="flag.JPG" alt="logo" height="60px" />
      </div>
      <div id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="welcome-section">
      <p>
        Hey I'm Hyde
      </p> 
      <p>
       A Web Developer
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">Projects here</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I change the space between "Hey I'm Hyde" and "A Web Developer"? Also is there a way to control the space between "Hey I'm Hide" and the top navbar?

Comment: @d234kdsafjk you can use `margin-top: -200px`